# Can union notation be simplified

Tags: notation

Just for context consider something like a set $\lbrace X_i \rbrace_{i \in I}$ where $I$ is also a set. I must say I'm more familiar with the sequencial notation $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ but I guess this makes it less of a set-related question.
Should we need to refer to the set whose elements are the elements of the elements of the set $\lbrace X_i \rbrace_{i \in I}$ we would use the notation $\cup_{i\in I} X_i$. However, if the set $\lbrace X_i \rbrace_{i \in I}$ was given a name, like $S$, then we would write $\cup_{s\in S} s$. But then why not write $\cup_S$ ? It seems totally unambiguous to me. I'm inclined to think that no extra information is given by that $s$ in the indices since it is $s$ itself that plays the role of the elements to be united, and not a function of $s$.
Is this notation ever used ?

Comment: For a set $S$ you may write $\bigcup S:=\{x:\exists A\in S$ such that $x\in A\}$. For instance, if $S=\{A,B\}$, then $\bigcup S=A\cup B$.

Comment: I've seen this before but I need to ask. For me, $A \cup B = \cup_{X \in \lbrace A,B \rbrace } X$. You wrote it $A \cup B = \cup \lbrace A,B \rbrace$ and this is another issue for me.

Comment: It is just notation. $\bigcup_{X\in\{A,B\}}X$ is also okay.

Comment: In both notations, the cup's argument isn't of the same type, $X$ is a subset of the resulting set, whereas $\lbrace A,B \rbrace$ isn't. Is that not a problem ? I mean is it always clear what is meant ? Adding $S \in I$ to $\cup S$ actually changes $S$ into a subset of the whole union.

Comment: No, it's not an issue, because in one you have a subscript and the other you have not. So there are no clashes.